# Trigger accordion with an external button/image and vice versa

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a few images that in a click event open their respective accordion text, I'm using this code for this and is working fine:

SCRIPT

```
$('#openfirst').click(function() {
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    active: 0
  });
});
$('#opensecond').click(function() {
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    active: 1
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <p id="openfirst">
      <img class="imgs" id="img1" />
    </p>
</div>
```

etc...

When you click the image it changes for a different one, I'm using this code for this and is working fine as well:

SCRIPT

```
var imgactive = $('.imgs');
imgactive.on('click', function(){
    imgactive.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The situation is that the accordion works perfect for itself, the images are linked to the accordion and are working as well (click image > image background changes and its respective accordion opens), my problem is that I don't know how to link the accordion with the images so in the event of click the accordion its respective image changes as well.

Thanks for reading and if you can help.. that's great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event so you can change you button image/state according to the new expanded panel; doc:

> Triggered after a panel has been activated (after animation
>   completes). If the accordion was previously collapsed, ui.oldHeader
>   and ui.oldPanel will be empty jQuery objects. If the accordion is
>   collapsing, ui.newHeader and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            alert($(ui.newHeader).attr("id"))
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7Ak94/1

Comment: Thanks @Edward to answer me, how can I know which accordion have been clicked?, I have .accordion in <ul> and I need to know the <li> id

Comment: You can get the current accordion id with $(ui.newHeader).attr("id") see: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7Ak94/1/